# Estou com problema com envio de vídeo ao servidor

Tags: php, html, linux, ubuntu

Olá tudo bem ? Estou tendo problemas com envio de vídeo ao servidor, com imagem (o mesmo código praticamente) ele envia, porém com vídeos não. Meu servidor é uma VPS Linux Ubuntu, tenho o painel vestaCP para gerencia a Hospedagem.

Já dei permissão chmod -R 777 para a pasta e mesmo assim ele não envia o vídeo.

Segue código abaixo.

```
<form name="cadastrar novos cursos" method="post" action="../backend/php/novaaula.php?id=<?php echo $uuid_curso; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label>Nome da aula <i>*</i></label>
<input id="name" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Nome do curso" required="" autocomplete="off">
<br>
<label>Vídeo <i>*</i> (.avi .mov .mp4)</label>
<input id="file" type="FILE" name="file" required="" autocomplete="off">
<br>
<label>Escreva aqui o que aprendemos nesse aula <i>*</i></label>
<textarea id="oqueaprendemos" type="text" name="oqueaprendemos" placeholder="O que aprendemos nesse aula" required="" autocomplete="off"></textarea>
<br>
<button id="save">Cadastrar</button>
</form>

$_UP['pasta'] = '../../../portal.claudeteiwata.com.br/assets/cursos/videos/';
// Extensoes permitidas dos vídeo
$_UP['extensoesvideo'] = array('avi', 'mov', 'mp4');
// Verifica se a extensao do arquivo é compativel com as extensoes acima
$extensao = strtolower(end(explode('.', $_FILES['file']['name'])));
if (array_search($extensao, $_UP['extensoesvideo']) === false) {
    header('Location: ../../registernewcourse/#errorvideo');
    return;
}
// Troca o nome do arquivo para outro.
$nomefinalvideo = $uuid_file.'.'.$extensao;

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $_UP['pasta'] . $nomefinalvideo)) {
  $sqlInseriraula  = mysqli_query($conexao, "INSERT INTO aulas(uuid_curso, uuid_aula, nome, oqueaprendemos, enderecovideo)
  VALUES ('$uuid_curso','$uuid_aula','$nome', '$oqueaprendemos', '$nomefinalvideo')");

  header('Location: ../../#certo');
}else {
  // header('Location: ../../curso/#errorvideocarregar');
}
```